# Unable to get node value of XML using XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

My XML looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope`enter code here`
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <platformMsgs:documentInfo
            xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <platformMsgs:nsId>WEBSERVICES_3479023</platformMsgs:nsId>
        </platformMsgs:documentInfo>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <addListResponse
            xmlns="">
            <platformMsgs:writeResponseList
                xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                <platformCore:status isSuccess="true"
                    xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"/>
                    <platformMsgs:writeResponse>
                        <platformCore:status isSuccess="false"
                            xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                            <platformCore:statusDetail type="ERROR">
                                <platformCore:code>DUP_ENTITY</platformCore:code>
                                <platformCore:message>This entity already exists.</platformCore:message>
                            </platformCore:statusDetail>
                        </platformCore:status>
                    </platformMsgs:writeResponse>
                </platformMsgs:writeResponseList>
            </addListResponse>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

For getting value using XPath, I have written the below class:

```
package com.scholastic.intl.esb.integration.resource;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;

public class SimpleNamespaceContext implements NamespaceContext {

    private final Map<String, String> PREF_MAP = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public SimpleNamespaceContext(final Map<String, String> prefMap) {
        PREF_MAP.putAll(prefMap);       
    }

    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        return PREF_MAP.get(prefix);
    }

    public String getPrefix(String uri) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public Iterator getPrefixes(String uri) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

And the below code is supposed to read the value of platformCore:message:

```
String xPathStr = "/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/addListResponse/platformMsgs:writeResponseList/platformCore:status/platformMsgs:writeResponse/platformCore:status/platformCore:statusDetail/platformCore:message";

XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            Map<String, String> prefMap = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
                put("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
                put("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
                put("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
                put("platformMsgs", "urn:messages_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com");
                put("platformCore", "urn:core_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com");
            }};
            xPath.setNamespaceContext(new SimpleNamespaceContext(prefMap));
            System.out.println("Expression value: "+xPath.evaluate(xPathStr, new InputSource(new StringReader(netSuiteResponse))));
```

Where netSuiteResponse is the input SOAP message in SOAP format, but no value is getting printed in the Sysout statement.

Please suggest me what is going wrong here and how to do it correctly.

Regards,
Anirban.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't deal with empty namspaces like that, you can match name though.

```
    String xPathStr = "/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/*[name()='addListResponse']"
            + "/platformMsgs:writeResponseList"
            + "/platformCore:status/@isSuccess"
            // + "/platformMsgs:writeResponse/platformCore:status/platformCore:statusDetail/platformCore:message";
            ;
    String xPathStr2 = "/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/*[name()='addListResponse']"
            + "/platformMsgs:writeResponseList"
            + "/platformMsgs:writeResponse"
            + "/platformCore:status"
            + "/platformCore:statusDetail"
            + "/platformCore:message";
            ;
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    Map<String, String> prefMap = new HashMap<String, String>() {
        {
            put("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
            put("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            put("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            put("platformMsgs", "urn:messages_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com");
            put("platformCore", "urn:core_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com");
        }
    };
    xPath.setNamespaceContext(new SimpleNamespaceContext(prefMap));
    System.out.println(
            "Expression value: " + xPath.evaluate(xPathStr, new InputSource(new StringReader(example))));
    System.out.println(
            "Expression value: " + xPath.evaluate(xPathStr2, new InputSource(new StringReader(example))));
```

Will result in:

```
Expression value: true
Expression value: This entity already exists.
```